# How can import blogger posts using custome xml or any other way?

Tags: xml, blogs, blogger

I tried to import 50 posts but its take long time with continue showing writing post message but not getting any error.

My step:
1.backup content as xml using blogger setting option.
2.add custom post details as same as existing xml tags and format.
3.using import content option and upload xml file without publishing option.

But it is successful for 1 or 2 times but now it is not working for 5 post also.
I followed blogger restrictions that 4 import a day with 50 post.

Please guide if have any option to upload post in blogger.
I am not migrated post from wordpress or any other blog.it is custom posts which needs to upload in bulk within google terms.

Comment: how can i add multiple posts using this template code you gave me

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately blogger does not notify you when you have errors in your xml. It is not importing it. In my case it takes 30 sec to import 200+ posts.

Also what i have see is that whenever i import posts i never check the the publish immediately checkbox because this basically takes more time to import, regardless whether your xml is valid.

So:

1. Have a valid xml (test one post for starters, date format , correct closing of tags etc)
2. As soon as you import one correctly..
3. Try to import more, but do not check the "Publish Immediately" check box.

That worked for me.

The process you are using seems correct.

I am using the below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns0:feed <xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<ns0:generator>Blogger</ns0:generator>
<ns0:entry>
<ns0:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008/kind#post" />
<ns0:category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="CATEGORY C" />
<ns0:category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="CATEGORY D" />
<ns0:id>Sample Blog Post</ns0:id><ns0:content type="html">Blogger CONTENT 2</ns0:content> 
<ns0:published>2019-10-30T03:22:00.001-07:00</ns0:published> 
<ns0:title type="html">Sample Blog Post</ns0:title> 
</ns0:entry>
</ns0:feed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now I tried to import to my blogger and this format work for me.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
<generator version='7.00' uri='https://www.blogger.com'>Blogger</generator>
<entry>
  <id>1</id>
  <published>2019-11-28T01:18:00.005-08:00</published>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008/kind#post'/>
  <category scheme='http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#' term='LABELS'/>
  <title type='text'>TEST IMPORT POST</title>
  <content type='html'>KONTEN POST TEST</content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Don't forget put `<published>` and `<id>`

Answer (score 0):

2022... this works on my recent blogger.com blog

it's from a post generator on sneeit.com [here](https://sneeit.com/spotdummy-blogger-demo-data-generator-for-template-developers)

I think that blogger.com has some limits on how many files you can upload per day (or maybe the total volume in the file.  I was just trying to find *one* valid file format and this is the one which works... it posts the full text of the "article" into a post in a blogger.com blog).

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:feed xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <ns0:title type="html">Any Theme</ns0:title>
  <ns0:generator>Blogger</ns0:generator>
  <ns0:link href="http://www.sneeit.com" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" />
  <ns0:link href="http://www.sneeit.com" rel="alternate" type="text/html" />
  <ns0:updated>2018-12-05T16:35:50Z</ns0:updated>
  <ns0:entry>
    <ns0:category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="Heath" />
    <ns0:category scheme="http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#" term="Nutrition" />
    <ns0:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008/kind#post" />
    <ns0:id>post-10</ns0:id>
    <ns0:author>
      <ns0:name>Tien Nguyen</ns0:name>
    </ns0:author>
    <ns0:content type="html">&lt;div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-xeuA6Ac9EJk/VffMDx0-hBI/AAAAAAAAOJI/RLMUCFMV92w/s1600/health_fitness-and-exercise_318K.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right:
      1em;"&gt;&lt;img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-xeuA6Ac9EJk/VffMDx0-hBI/AAAAAAAAOJI/RLMUCFMV92w/s1600/health_fitness-and-exercise_318K.jpg" alt="Dummy Image With Link to Itself"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;9 things that won't happen in
      fitness programs. Why nutrition facts should be 1 of the 7 deadly sins. Why you'll never succeed at vaccination schedules. How fitness magazines are making the world a better place. Why our world would end if vaccine ingredients disappeared. 13
      myths uncovered about healthy eating tips. 15 least favorite travel vaccines. How healthy eating meal plans are the new healthy eating meal plans. The 11 worst weight loss supplements in history. The 13 worst healthy eating tips in history.&lt;br
      /&gt;&lt;!--more--&gt;&lt;br /&gt;How high cholesterol food can make you sick. Why weight loss supplements are the new black. 15 things about weight loss supplements your kids don't want you to know. How cholesterol levels can help you live a better
      life. Why you'll never succeed at preventative medicines. The oddest place you will find health care solutions. Why health questions should be 1 of the 7 deadly sins. Ways your mother lied to you about cholesterol levels. Why the world would end
      without fitness programs. Why mom was right about weight loss meal plans.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Jt2RanYUyhM/VffMCI_D0yI/AAAAAAAAOIY/jURMkJ0bCMc/s1600/health_body-building-for-girls_141K.jpg"
      imageanchor="1" style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"&gt;&lt;img border="0" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Jt2RanYUyhM/VffMCI_D0yI/AAAAAAAAOIY/jURMkJ0bCMc/s1600/health_body-building-for-girls_141K.jpg" width="320"
      alt="Dummy Image With Link to Itself"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;19 things you don't want to hear about health questions. The 15 biggest medicine shop blunders. Expose: you're losing money by not using fitness programs. Expose: you're losing money
      by not using health informatics. Why our world would end if healthy eating facts disappeared. 6 things that won't happen in weight loss meal plans. Why mom was right about fitness programs. What experts are saying about travel medicines. 19 myths
      uncovered about fitness programs. What wikipedia can't tell you about travel vaccines.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;12 things that won't happen in primary preventions. 9 things you don't want to hear about fitness magazines. Ways your mother lied to you
      about travel vaccines. Why primary preventions are afraid of the truth. What wikipedia can't tell you about nutrition facts. The oddest place you will find health quotes. Will weight loss meal plans ever rule the world? The best ways to utilize
      health care providers. How nutrition facts can help you live a better life. The best ways to utilize cholesterol levels.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OSCe_Ifv6z4/VffMEP73ogI/AAAAAAAAOJE/JWBvtEQUijQ/s1600/health_fitness-is-easy_128K.jpg"
      imageanchor="1" style="clear: right; float: right; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-left: 1em;"&gt;&lt;img border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OSCe_Ifv6z4/VffMEP73ogI/AAAAAAAAOJE/JWBvtEQUijQ/s1600/health_fitness-is-easy_128K.jpg" width="320" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;14
      things your boss expects you know about travel vaccines. Why you'll never succeed at fitness programs. The evolution of weight loss success stories. Why the next 10 years of relapse prevention worksheets will smash the last 10. What experts are
      saying about healthy eating meal plans. 7 bs facts about fitness equipment everyone thinks are true. The complete beginner's guide to weight loss success stories. What wikipedia can't tell you about travel vaccines. What wikipedia can't tell you
      about healthy eating tips. 8 least favorite cholesterol lowering food.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Why our world would end if travel vaccines disappeared. If you read one article about weight loss supplements read this one. If you read one article about
      healthy eating tips read this one. If you read one article about healthy eating tips read this one. Why the next 10 years of fitness programs will smash the last 10. The only health question resources you will ever need. The 13 best resources for
      travel vaccines. Naturopathic medicines by the numbers. 5 things your boss expects you know about fitness equipment. How preventative medicines can help you live a better life.</ns0:content>
    <ns0:published>2018-11-28T16:22:28Z</ns0:published>
    <ns0:title type="html">Why your preventative medicine never works out the way you plan</ns0:title>
    <ns0:link href="http://www.sneeit.com/?p=10" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" />
    <ns0:link href="http://www.sneeit.com/?p=10" rel="alternate" type="text/html" />
  </ns0:entry>
</ns0:feed>
```

Comment: how can i add multiple posts using this template code you gave